# Thrown timeout in Python on Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, boost

I'm wroking c++ with embedding python using boost::python 
development environment is Windows 7, Visual Studio 2012, boost 1.55(64bit), Python 2.7.10(64bit).

the python module uses UDP. It works well on python on console(cmd). but if i run this module on C++(visual studio), recv sockect throws time out exception.

I'm using https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/bybop
In here, recvfrom method of _read_loop of Bybop_NetworkAL.py throws time out.

p.s Sorry for my not enough english.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code you are using and error?

Comment: You can see in [here](https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/bybop/blob/master/src/Bybop_NetworkAL.py#L104). and [running code](https://github.com/Parrot-Developers/bybop/blob/master/samples/interactive.py)  @ajshort

Answer (score 0):

I'd post this as a comment if I could... Look into the datetime module, http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html - You can use datetime.now() and timedelta to accomplish the same thing as you have above.